# PERCONA MYSQL ERROR Error Code: 1034. Incorrect key file for table

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona

im trying to import a table after partial backup or full with percona 8.0 and im having problems with only 1 table, the size of the table = 14 GB. im doing the steps following all oficial forums:

1. full backup: xtrabackup --backup --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --target-dir=/backup/ --parallel=4 --user='root' --password='pass' --no-timestamp
2. create table with same structure no data.
3. SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
4. alter table mytable discard tablespace;
5. cp mytable.ibd /var/lib/mysql/database/ & chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/db/mytable.ibd
6. SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
7. alter table mytable import tablespace;

after all this steps i got this error:

Error Code: 1034. Incorrect key file for table 'mytable'; try to repair it

and in mysql.log i got:

[MY-012762] [InnoDB] Page offset doesn't match file offset: page offset: 262144, file offset: 262144

i only get the error some tables, if i restore full backup with --copy-back all tables are OK!

what can i do? i tried increase change directory /tmp in my.cnf but nothing work.

https://forums.percona.com/discussion/55472/percona-mysql-error-error-code-1034-incorrect-key-file-for-table#latest

Comment: Is that table InnoDB?

Comment: yes mate, InnoDB

Comment: Hmmm...  Consider writing a bug at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: i did mate, very rare this situation, i dont know why, maybe for the size of table 14 GB or index idk

Comment: Please put a link to the bug so other SO users can find it.  They might upvote it ("Affects me").

Comment: https://forums.percona.com/discussion/55472/percona-mysql-error-error-code-1034-incorrect-key-file-for-table#latest

Comment: done mate! THANKS

Comment: I have the same problem, following a different procedure, though: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-table-import.html In my case, it's a large 22GB IBD table file. I checked the Percona Forum response by jrivera and wonder if it's not a table size issue, since his example has 1 row only. I had no issues importing any of my 20+ other tables.